# websharper element ids

Tags: selenium, f#, websharper

We plan to use WebSharper for our web interface. The problem is that our integration tests are based on selenium and use the ids of the page elements for clicking and filling data.
For this reason we need to be able to specify ids for all the relevant elements in the page.

For non-form elements we can do this:
A [HRef (ctx.Link Home)] -< [Text "Home" ] -< [Id "home"]

How can we do it for the input fields inside a formlet?

Thanks

UPDATE: In the end we decided not to use websharper formlets. One reason is that we can't assign IDs to form elements and thus our testing method doesn't work anymore. The other reason is the table based layout which don't fit well in our design. We will still use websharper but without formlets library

Comment: I'm pretty sure input fields get their own random id from the JS-based Formlets library. You should use WebSharper's JQuery API to select it (not by id, but but supplying the Formlet's element).

Comment: The table-based formlets are a real pain point. I raised a bug for this with intellifactory 12 months ago. Perhaps they need some gentle prodding :)

https://bitbucket.org/IntelliFactory/websharper/issue/9/table-free-formlets

Answer (score 1):

Why you explicitly need to use id's for selenium tests? 
I am certain that you know this but I will put link
http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html.

From my xp xpath is more reliable than id's and I saw pages where was plenty of same ids (although I scraped wild web not internal application :-) )

Comment: Our tests are written in Python and look like this:  
...  
session.User_Create.click()  
session.Name.text="someuser"  
session.DisplayName.text="some user display name"  
session.Password.text="somepass"  
session.Save.click()  
This is accomplished by having a thin layer above selenium.  
  
Changing these to use xpath will probably take a lot of work and they won't look that clean.  
  
Same IDs in one page is not the case because the existing UI was written to support this testing method.